# Difference between paste() and paste0()

Tags: r, paste

Being new to R, can someone please explain the difference between `paste()` and `paste0()`, what I had understood from some post is that

```
paste0("a", "b") === paste("a", "b", sep="")
```

Even I tried something like this

```
a <- c("a","b","c")
b <- c("y","w","q")
paste(a,b,sep = "_")
**output**
"a_y" "b_w" "c_q"
```

### using `paste0()`

```
a <- c("a","b","c")
b <- c("y","w","q")
paste0(a,b,sep = "_")
**output**
"ay_" "bw_" "cq_"
```

Is it just that `paste()` uses separator between elements and `paste0()` uses separator after the elements?

Comment: `paste0` doesn't have a `sep` parameter. Try `paste0(a,b,blabla = "_")`

Comment: from `?paste`: _paste0(..., collapse) is equivalent to paste(..., sep = "", collapse), slightly more efficiently._

Comment: use `paste` instead of `paste0` if you want to use a separator. The whole purpose of using `paste0` is in order to have the separator predefined. This is a classic XY problem.

Comment: Alright this is a bit clear..Thanks!

Comment: https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2013/09/15/paste-paste0-and-sprintf-2/ I blogged on the subject

Comment: alos, `paste0` won't be correctly interpreted by `expression` (try `plot(0:1, 0:1, main=expression(paste(delta, "=3")))` and then `plot(0:1, 0:1, main=expression(paste0(delta, "=3")))`)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

As explained [in this blog by Tyler Rinker](https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2013/09/15/paste-paste0-and-sprintf-2/):

> `paste` has 3 arguments.
>
> `paste (..., sep = " ", collapse = NULL)` The `...` is the stuff you
>   want to paste together and sep and collapse are the guys to get it
>   done. There are three basic things I paste together:
>
> - A bunch of individual character strings.
> - 2 or more strings pasted element for element.
> - One string smushed together.
>
> Here's an example of each, though not with the correct arguments
>
> `paste("A", 1, "%")`       #A bunch of individual character strings.
>
> `paste(1:4, letters[1:4])` #2 or more strings pasted element for
>   element.
>
> `paste(1:10)`              #One string smushed together. Here's the
>   sep/collapse rule for each:
>
> - A bunch of individual character strings – You want sep
> - 2 or more strings pasted element for element. – You want sep
> - One string smushed together.- Smushin requires collapse
>
> `paste0` is short for: `paste(x, sep="")` So it allows us to be lazier
>   and more efficient.
>
> `paste0("a", "b") == paste("a", "b", sep="") ## [1] TRUE`

Comment: @deepesh This is not his blog. Please give credit where it's due. This is Tyler Rinkers blog and he linked it in comments.

Answer (score 27):

In simple words,

`paste()` is like concatenation using separation factor,
whereas,

`paste0()` is like append function using separation factor.

Adding some more references to above discussion, below try outs can be useful to avoid confusion:

```
> paste("a","b")  #Here default separation factor is " " i.e. a space

[1] "a b"  

> paste0("a","b") #Here default separation factor is "" i.e a null

[1] "ab"

> paste("a","b",sep="-")

[1] "a-b"

> paste0("a","b",sep="-")

[1] "ab-"

> paste(1:4,"a")

[1] "1 a" "2 a" "3 a" "4 a"

> paste0(1:4,"a")

[1] "1a" "2a" "3a" "4a"

> paste(1:4,"a",sep="-")

[1] "1-a" "2-a" "3-a" "4-a"

> paste0(1:4,"a",sep="-")

[1] "1a-" "2a-" "3a-" "4a-"
```

Comment: `paste0(1:4,"a",sep="-")` is just equal with `paste0(1:4,"a","-")` or `paste0(sep=1:4,"a","-")` or `paste0(aaa=1:4,bbb="a",ccc="-")`

Answer (score 7):

Let me put it in a simple words.. `paste0` will automatically exclude the space in your concatenation..

For Example, I want to create a Training and test path..here's the code..

```
> Curr_date=format(Sys.Date(),"%d-%b-%y")

> currentTrainPath = paste("Train_",Curr_date,".RData")

> currentTrainPath

[1] "Train_ 11-Jun-16 .RData"

> Curr_date=format(Sys.Date(),"%d-%b-%y")

> currentTrainPath = paste0("Train_",Curr_date,".RData")

> currentTrainPath

[1] "Train_11-Jun-16.RData"
```