# What is the difference between paste/paste0 and str_c?

Tags: r, stringr

I don't seem to see a difference between `paste`/`paste0` and `str_c` for combining a single vector into a single string, multiple strings into one string, or multiple vectors into a single string.

While I was writing the question I found this: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.3.1/topics/str_c.  The community example from richie@datacamp.com says the difference is is that `str_c` treats blanks as blanks (not as NAs) and recycles more appropriately.  Any other differences?

Comment: One difference is that `str_c` is faster.

Comment: Though the speed difference seems to be almost negligible. Benchmarking `paste0` vs `str_c` with inputs `letters, letters`, the time difference is about 30%, but that 30% is 2.1 microseconds on my computer, or 0.0000021 seconds. It would be strange code where `paste` is the bottleneck...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36279800/difference-between-paste-and-paste0

Comment: @user5249203, I get the difference between `paste` and `paste0`, I'm trying to figure out how these differ from `str_c`

Comment: relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53118271/difference-between-paste-str-c-str-join-stri-join-stri-c-stri-pa/53118273#53118273

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`paste0(..., collapse = NULL)`is a wrapper for `paste(..., sep = "", collapse = NULL)`, which means there is no separator. In other words, with `paste0()` you can not apply some sort of separator, while you do have that option with `paste()`, whereas a single space is the default.

`str_c(..., sep = "", collapse = NULL)` is equivalent to `paste()`, which means you do have the option to customize your desired separator. The difference is for `str_c()` the default is no separator, so it acts just like `paste0()` as a default.

`Paste()` and `paste0()` are both functions from the base package, whereas `str_c()` comes from the stringr package.

I did not test/microbenchmark it, but from my experience I do agree to Ryan `str_c()` is generally faster.

Comment: I can't agree with you that  str_c is faster than paste0.

Answer (score 1):

From https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/string-manipulation-with-stringr-in-r/introduction-to-stringr?ex=2

> There are two key ways `str_c()` differs from `paste()`. First, the
> default separator is an empty string, `sep = ""`, as opposed to a space,
> so it's more like `paste0()`. This is an example of a stringr function,
> performing a similar operation to a base function, but using a default
> that is more likely to be what you want. {...}
>
> The second way `str_c()` differs to `paste()` is in its handling of
> missing values. `paste()` turns missing values into the string `"NA"`,
> whereas `str_c()` propagates missing values. That means combining
> any strings with a missing value will result in another missing value.