# Difference between `paste`, `str_c`, `str_join`, `stri_join`, `stri_c`, `stri_paste`?

Tags: r, stringr, stringi

What are the differences between all of these functions that seem very similar ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- `stri_join`, `stri_c`, and `stri_paste` come from package *`stringi`* and are pure aliases
- `str_c` comes from *`stringr`* and is just `stringi::stri_join` with a parameter `ignore_null` hardcoded to `TRUE` while `stringi::stri_join` has it set to `FALSE` by default. `stringr::str_join` is a deprecated alias for `str_c`

see:

```
library(stringi)
identical(stri_join, stri_c)
# [1] TRUE
identical(stri_join, stri_paste)
# [1] TRUE

library(stringr)
str_c
# function (..., sep = "", collapse = NULL) 
# {
#   stri_c(..., sep = sep, collapse = collapse, ignore_null = TRUE)
# }
# <environment: namespace:stringr>
```

`stri_join` is very similar to `base::paste` with a few differences enumerated below:

---

**1. `sep = ""` by default**

So it behaves more like `paste0` by default, but `paste0` lost its `sep` argument.

```
identical(paste0("a","b")        , stri_join("a","b"))
# [1] TRUE
identical(paste("a","b")         , stri_join("a","b",sep=" "))
# [1] TRUE
identical(paste("a","b", sep="-"), stri_join("a","b", sep="-"))
# [1] TRUE
```

`str_c` will behave just like `stri_join` here.

---

**2.  Behavior with `NA`**

if you paste to `NA` using `stri_join`, the result is `NA`, while `paste` converts `NA` to `"NA"`

```
paste0(c("a","b"),c("c",NA))
# [1] "ac"  "bNA"
stri_join(c("a","b"),c("c",NA))
# [1] "ac" NA
```

`str_c` will behave just like `stri_join` here as well

---

**3. Behavior with length `0` arguments**

When a length 0 value is encountered, `character(0)` is returned, except if `ignore_null` is set to `FALSE`, then the value is ignored. It is different from the behavior of `paste` which would convert the length `0` value to `""` and thus contain 2 consecutive separators in the output.

```
stri_join("a",NULL, "b")  
# [1] character(0)
stri_join("a",character(0), "b")  
# [1] character(0)

paste0("a",NULL, "b")
# [1] "ab"
stri_join("a",NULL, "b", ignore_null = TRUE)
# [1] "ab"
str_c("a",NULL, "b")
# [1] "ab"

paste("a",NULL, "b") # produces double space!
# [1] "a  b" 
stri_join("a",NULL, "b", ignore_null = TRUE, sep = " ")
# [1] "a b"
str_c("a",NULL, "b", sep = " ")
# [1] "a b"
```

---

**4. *`stri_join`* warns more**

```
paste(c("a","b"),c("c","d","e"))
# [1] "a c" "b d" "a e"
paste("a","b", sep = c(" ","-"))
# [1] "a b"

stri_join(c("a","b"),c("c","d","e"), sep = " ")
# [1] "a c" "b d" "a e"
# Warning message:
#   In stri_join(c("a", "b"), c("c", "d", "e"), sep = " ") :
#   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
stri_join("a","b", sep = c(" ","-"))
# [1] "a b"
# Warning message:
#   In stri_join("a", "b", sep = c(" ", "-")) :
#   argument `sep` should be one character string; taking the first one
```

---

**5. *`stri_join`* is faster**

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  stringi = stri_join(rep("a",1000000),rep("b",1000),"c",sep=" "),
  base    = paste(rep("a",1000000),rep("b",1000),"c")
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr       min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval cld
# stringi  88.54199  93.4477  97.31161  95.17157  96.8879 131.9737   100  a 
# base    166.01024 169.7189 178.31065 171.30910 176.3055 215.5982   100   b
```