# Handling zero length character vectors as empty strings

Tags: r, paste, purrr, stringr

By way of example, see the extraction of Twitter handles below. The target is to have a character string that resembles `tweets` but has only handles separated by commas. `str_replace_all` yields empty vectors when no matches are found and that threw some unexpected errors further down the track.

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

tweets <- c(
  "",
  "This tweet has no handles",
  "This is a tweet for @you",
  "This is another tweet for @you and @me",
  "This, @bla, is another tweet for @me and @you"
)


mention_rx <- "@\\w+"
```

This was my first attempt:

```
map_chr(tweets, ~str_c(str_extract_all(.x, mention_rx)[[1]], collapse = ", "))
#> Error: Result 1 must be a single string, not a character vector of length 0
```

Then I played around with things:

```
mentions <- map(tweets, ~str_c(str_extract_all(.x, mention_rx)[[1]], collapse = ", "))

mentions
#> [[1]]
#> character(0)
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> character(0)
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "@you"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "@you, @me"
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] "@bla, @me, @you"

as.character(mentions)
#> [1] "character(0)"    "character(0)"    "@you"            "@you, @me"      
#> [5] "@bla, @me, @you"
```

Until it dawned on me that `paste` could also be used here:

```
map_chr(tweets, ~paste(str_extract_all(.x, mention_rx)[[1]], collapse = ", "))
#> ""                ""                "@you"            "@you, @me"       "@bla, @me, @you"
```

My questions are:

- Is there a more elegant way of getting there?
- Why doesn't `str_c` behave the same as `paste` with an identical `collapse` argument?
- Why don't `as.character` and `map_chr` recognise a character vector
  of length zero as equivalent to an empty string but `paste` does?

I found some good references on [str(i)_c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53118271/difference-between-paste-str-c-str-join-stri-join-stri-c-stri-pa/53118273#53118273), [paste](https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2013/09/15/paste-paste0-and-sprintf-2/), and the [difference between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50818932/what-is-the-difference-between-paste-paste0-and-str-c); but none of these addressed the situation with empty strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to `map` over `tweets`, `str_extract_all` can handle vectors

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(tweets, mention_rx)

#[[1]]
#character(0)

#[[2]]
#character(0)

#[[3]]
#[1] "@you"

#[[4]]
#[1] "@you" "@me" 

#[[5]]
#[1] "@bla" "@me"  "@you"
```

Now if you need one comma-separated string then you can use `map`

```
purrr::map_chr(str_extract_all(tweets, mention_rx), toString)
#[1] ""    ""      "@you"     "@you, @me"      "@bla, @me, @you"
```

---

To answer the "why" questions, we can look at the documentation of `paste` and `str_c` functions.

From `?paste`

> Vector arguments are recycled as needed, with zero-length arguments being recycled to "".

From `?str_c`

> Zero length arguments are removed.

Hence, by default `str_c` removes zero-length arguments which makes the output a 0-length string which fails for `map_chr` but it works with `map` as `map` returns a list

```
map(tweets, ~str_c(str_extract_all(.x, mention_rx)[[1]], collapse = ", "))

#[[1]]
#character(0)

#[[2]]
#character(0)

#[[3]]
 #[1] "@you"

#[[4]]
#[1] "@you, @me"

#[[5]]
#[1] "@bla, @me, @you"
```

Comment: Hey Ronak, thanks so much! I had been working with unequal numbers of patterns and strings so I got too used to this mapping over `stringr` functions... Not sure if it's justified even in that case. Do you have any inkling as to the possible answers for the "why" questions?

Comment: @FonsMA Updated the answer with some explanation to it. Hope it is helpful.