# How to remove space before dot using paste() function in R

Tags: r, string, function, paste

I try to use the paste function to print some strings, and numeric in R such as:

```
method = "binomial"
b = 5
paste("The method is", a, "and the value is", b, ".")
```

and the result looks like

```
"The method is binomial and the result is 5 ."
```

How to remove the space between 5 and .? I want the result looks like

```
"The method is binomial and the value is 5."
```

If I am using the paste0("The method is", a, "and the value is", b, ".") the result looks like

```
"The method isbinomialand the result is5."
```

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to consult [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36279800/difference-between-paste-and-paste0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Paste0(...)` or `paste(..., sep = "")` work fine, but I find the `glue()` offers a clean way of concatenating strings, without lots of opening and closing quotes.

In this case:

`glue::glue("The values are {a} and {b}.")`

Answer (score 2):

Use `paste0`:

```r
paste0("The values are ", a, " and ", b, ".")
"The values are 4 and 5."
```

or `paste("The values are ", a, " and ", b, ".", sep = "")`

Comment: I am sorry I edited the question. I got a slightly different problem when the variable value is a string, not a numeric. But your suggestion does work if the two variables are numerical values.

Comment: @MKHuda Note that I added blanks between `are` and the quote `"` and between the quotes `"` and `and`