# Error while downloading multiple HTML pages and then web-scraping in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

This is the base URL that I want to web scrape:
http://ctri.nic.in/Clinicaltrials/pmaindet2.php?trialid=x*, where *x = 1,2,3..so on.* Not all numbers exist.

For a single URL, I have created a Rmarkdown script, which works perfectly fine. Following is the snippet for part of whole script.

```
myurl = "http://ctri.nic.in/Clinicaltrials/pmaindet2.php?trialid=367"
download.file(myurl, destfile = "mypage.html", quiet=TRUE)
pointer = read_html("mypage.html")

webpage = html_nodes(pointer, "tr") 
webpage = html_table(webpage)
webpage = webpage[[1]]
webpage = webpage[-1,]

commonTable = NULL

commonTable$CTRI_Number = as.character(webpage %>% 
                                        filter(X1 %like% "CTRI Number") %>% 
                                        select(X2) %>% 
                                        str_extract_all("\\D+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+"))
                                        
commonTable$reg_type = as.character(webpage %>% filter(X1 %like% "CTRI Number") %>% select(X2))

commonTable$Registered_on = as.character(webpage %>% 
                                         filter(X1 %like% "CTRI Number") %>% 
                                         select(X2) %>% 
                                         str_extract_all("\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{4}"))

reg_details = data.frame(CTRI_Number = commonTable$CTRI_Number,
                         Registered_on = commonTable$Registered_on,
                         reg_type = commonTable$reg_type)
```

I am facing errors when I'm trying to run the same code in the loop for multiple files. I'm currently trying for a batch of 20 pages.
Following is the loop.

```
set_config(use_proxy(url="http://proxy.XXXX.ac.in", port="my port"))

ids = c(1:20)

for (i in seq_along(ids)) {
  myurl = paste("http://ctri.nic.in/Clinicaltrials/pmaindet2.php?trialid=", i) 
  myurl = gsub(" ","",myurl)
  if(http_error(myurl)) next
  
  download.file(myurl, destfile = "mypage.html", quiet = TRUE)
  pointer = read_html(myurl)
  webpage = html_nodes(pointer, "tr") 
  webpage = html_table(webpage)
  webpage = webpage[[1]]
  webpage = webpage[-1,]
  
  commonTable = NULL

  commonTable$CTRI_Number = as.character(webpage %>% 
                                        filter(X1 %like% "CTRI Number") %>% 
                                        select(X2) %>% 
                                        str_extract_all("\\D+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+"))
  
  commonTable$reg_type = as.character(webpage %>% filter(X1 %like% "CTRI Number") %>% select(X2))

  commonTable$Registered_on = as.character(webpage %>% 
                                         filter(X1 %like% "CTRI Number") %>% 
                                         select(X2) %>% 
                                         str_extract_all("\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{4}"))

  reg_details = data.frame(CTRI_Number = commonTable$CTRI_Number,
                         Registered_on = commonTable$Registered_on,
                         reg_type = commonTable$reg_type)
}
```

> Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : Timeout was reached: [ctri.nic.in]
> Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try to use `paste0` instead of `paste` while creating `myurl`. You can find more details about the differences between both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36279800/difference-between-paste-and-paste0)

tl;dr: the default separation factor for `paste` is " ", and for `paste0` is "".

Comment: @Bart, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I would suspect the proxy, which is set `set_config(use_proxy(url="http://proxy.XXXX.ac.in", port="my port"))` - is it required to access the web page?

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko It is not compulsory. I get the same error with or without proxy.

Comment: I completely missed your error with the timeout, as I tried the code myself and it works (scraps data). @Grzegorz may be right - if it's not necessary, skip it. Else, try to set the pause between the loops, i.e. adding additional function at the end of your loop:

`testit <- function(x)
{
  p1 <- proc.time()
  Sys.sleep(x)
  proc.time() - p1 # The cpu usage should be negligible
}

testit(3.7) #pause time in sec`

Comment: @Bart, When you ran the code, did it scrap for multiple pages or single?

Comment: It's working for a while, until `i` reaches 4 - then, it comes to error like ℹ Input `..1` is `X1 %like% "CTRI Number"`. `x object 'X1' not found`. I would suggest to check, if the page content have all neccessary information, or put it in kind of check (if-then). Otherwise should be okish.

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko I'm getting very different error. S0mething like Error in `Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : 
  Timeout was reached: [ctri.nic.in] Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds`

Comment: @Jaishree, then I would suspect the connection itself. Are you able to reach the address with browser like mozilla? Could you try `curl` package for connection/downloading the files? BTW, `curl` has a nice check for response headers.

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko I haven't used the curl package before.